# Problems with handleChange function on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I have a problem with the handleChange function.

My program loads a list of users with jsonplaceholder data and has 'Edit' button, clicking on this button a form appears with the selected user's data.

**Problem**: When I try to edit some of the fields, the form "refresh".

```
//User.js (contains the function)



import React from 'react';
import UserEdit from './components/UserEdit';
import UsersList from './components/UsersList'
import './App.css';

class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      displayList: 'block',
      displayForm: 'none',
      edit: false,

      userEdit: {
        id: null,
        name: "",
        email: "",
        address: {
          street: "",
          suite: "",
          city: "",
          zipcode: ""
        },
        phone: ""
      }
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUsersList();
  }

  getUsersList(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response  => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({users: json}));
  }

  getUserEdit(){
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + this.state.UserEdit.id;

    fetch(url)
      .then(response  => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({userEdit: json}));
  }

  handleClick(id){

    if (this.state.displayList === 'block') {
      this.setState({UserEdit: {id: id}});
      this.setState({displayList: 'none', displayForm: 'block'})
      this.setState({edit: true})
    }
    else {
      this.setState({displayList: 'block', displayForm: 'none'})
      this.setState({edit: false})
    }
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [event.target.value]: event.target.value
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }

  render(){
    if (this.state.edit === false) {
      return (
        <UsersList
          users = {this.state.users}
          displayList = {this.state.displayList}
          handleClick = {this.handleClick}
        />
      );
    }

    else {
      this.getUserEdit();
      return(
        <UserEdit
          user = {this.state.userEdit}
          displayForm = {this.state.displayForm}
          handleChange = {this.handleChange}
          handleClick = {this.handleClick}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Users;




//UserEdit.js code

import React from 'react';

function UserEdit(props){
  return(
    <ul>
      <div style={{display: props.displayForm.form}} key={props.user.id}>
        <form>
          <h2>{props.user.name} </h2>
          <p>Email:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              value = {props.user.email}
              className="form-control"
              onChange={props.handleChange}
            />
          </p>
          <p>Address: </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Street:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="address.street"
                value={props.user.address ? props.user.address.street : ''}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={props.handleChange}
              />
            </li>
            <li>Suite:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="address.suite"
                value={props.user.address ? props.user.address.suite : ''}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={props.handleChange}
              />
            </li>
            <li>City:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="address.city"
                value={props.user.address ? props.user.address.city : ''}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={props.handleChange}
              />
            </li>
            <li>ZipCode:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="address.zipcode"
                value={props.user.address ? props.user.address.zipcode : ''}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={props.handleChange}
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p>Phone:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="phone"
              value = {props.user.phone}
              className="form-control"
              onChange={props.handleChange}
            />
          </p>
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => props.handleClick()}> Save </button>
        <hr></hr>
        </div>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I've tried to put on the console to see what happens.
E.g. The name street is 'Kulas Light', if I click on number 5, the input stay the same but the console appears 'Kulas Light5'

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-dtn0s)

Comment: Hi Catarina, could you send a CodeSandbox with the code to help you? Thank you :)

Comment: @fg93 How can I send this? I'm new on stack overflow

Comment: For the next time, Stackoverflow has a box to incorporate the code where you want them to help you and externally you also have this: https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21 :)

Comment: Hi Catarina, there are more than one problem out there, but to make sure I can provide a 100% working example, you can do a codesandbox, or: at least provide the piece of code that is responsible of rendering the `UserEdit` component inside of your `User.js` file.

Comment: @SultanH. I put all the code of User.js here

Comment: @fg93 I will try put here, thank you

Comment: @SultanH. I added a link with sandBox link in the end

Comment: @fg93, The link with sandBox link is in the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE #1:**
After the codesandbox provided in the question:

[Working Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-d8qzn?fontsize=14). as forked from the original code provided in the question.

- The only edits has been made are in `Users.js`
- Follow the comments to figure out what happened.

**Away from the Main Problem:**

- Save functionality isn't complete as it seems to actually not doing any POST for data

---

Besides Notice from Christopher up there, you need to be editing the exact value of the input in your state, like:

if you are editing `name` property, then you need to update it in `userEdits` which is in the state.

```
  handleChange(event){
    const newUserEdit = {...this.state.userEdit};

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      userEdit: {
        ...newUserEdit,
        [event.target.value]: event.target.value
      }
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }
```

This code would actually work, only if you dont have such names for your inputs, like: `address.zipcode` `address.suite`

I have made a small edit to the `handleChange` that would accept such a name and transpiles it to a readable `userEdit.address.name`:

```
  handleChange(event){
    const newUserEdit = {...this.state.userEdit};
    const { value, name } = event.target; //get name and value out of event.target
    if(name.indexOf('address.')){
      newUserEdit = {
        ...newUserEdit,
        address: {
          [name.split('.')[1]]: value
        }
      }
    } else {
      newUserEdit = {
        ...newUserEdit,
        [name]: value
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      userEdit: { ...newUserEdit }
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }
```

Comment: I emplemented that, but I think that now the problem is tha I can't edit the fields (input), I can't write there

Comment: I updated this around 1min before your comment, can you please double check?

Comment: I tried but I still can't, you can check it on my sandBox link, there I can't edit inputs too, maybe the problem now is on UserEdit.js, I don't know. Thank you

Comment: I am on it, I guess I found it.

Comment: @CatarinaBatista, I have updated the question, it's solved. I forked your sand box and it's now correctly editing. please follow the comments on the shared link up there under **UPDATE #1**.

Comment: I am Glad it's acceptable, and if you need somehelp with save functionality, or any related more illustration about what was going wrong, I'll be happy to tell.

Comment: It really helps me, beacause I'm learning react to my first job :) ty

Comment: Here is the first tip: [React Rendering Gotcha](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/react-rendering-misconception).

Wish you a good luck! you're welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a bother, but I got it  make the save function without method post, I saved in state. There is some problem?

Comment: Can you possibly open a new question for that with description to what are you trying to achieve, the expected behavior and the actual one?

Comment: Post the question's link in here so I may find it.

Comment: Here it is: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136138/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-the-method-post-when-editing-a-form-react[link]

Answer (score 1):

Your `handleChange()` is setting the object in the parent-state to be a single field.

```
handleChange(event){
    var change = {}
    change[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    this.setState(change) //change only has one key-value pair, whereas initially state had multiple key-values

    console.log(change)
}
```

Use the spread operator `{...}` to preserve the existing state of your component. Essentially, spread just means to take all the existing data (key-values) and use them in a new object. You can modify your `handleChange()` to this instead:

```
handleChange(event){
   this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   }, () => console.log(this.state) )
}
```

Additionally, `this.setState()` has a second argument that accepts a call-back function. Within that call-back we have access to the updated-state. So after your event successful completes, we can read the new data.

Comment: Or even without spread operator, let's say that she wants to update address, it can be done like ```this.setState({address: change})```

Comment: @zpouip That is very true :)

Comment: Or since it is used for more fields, then yeah, it makes sense like you wrote: ```this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})```. I think this should be enough also.

Comment: It's broad, there are more than only this problem in the question.

Comment: Only because the OP edited the question with what the state _actually_ looks like. This answer is correct for the code that was originally provided.

Comment: I changed the code, but I can't edit the entries, I just do one action, for example, I click on a keyboard key and the form updates automatically without letting me edit any more

Comment: @CatarinaBatista Yeah that makes sense. The way you handle state right now, you are turning controlled inputs into uncontrolled inputs, which would give an error. I can try to put your code in a sandbox and see whats wrong.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I will try to put my code in a sandbox and edit this question, thak you

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I added a link with sandBox link in the end if it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your handleChange you're setting the state to a new object each time which is destroying the existing state.

With the edit you made to your question here's how it should probably look. In each instance I'm dynamically setting a specific state key with your input name, and assigning it the input value. Because of the way your state is set up you have to check to see what the input name is to guide to updating the correct part of state.

```
handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }}) => {
  if (['street', 'suite', 'city', 'zipcode'].includes(name)) {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      userEdit: {
        ...prev.userEdit,
        address: { ...prev.userEdit.address, [name]: value }
      }
    }));
  } else {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      userEdit: { ...prev.userEdit, [name]: value }
    }));
  }
}
```

This also meant changing your address input names to simply "city" instead of "address.city" for example.

[Here's a sandbox using your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-glitter-slx16).

Note also, that because `setState` is normally async, you can't log the new state immediately. `setState` has a callback that you can use instead.

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState(this.setState({ userEdit: { [name]: value } },
    () => console.log(this.state)
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice one Andy :)

Comment: @Andy, I think that the problem now is that I can't edit the inputs, maybe you can check it on my sandBox link on the final of this post. Thank you for your help

Comment: I copied (most of) your code into that sandbox link in my answer. The inputs are editable. @CatarinaBatista

Comment: @Andy, I copied your code to my project but I still can't edit, I don't know why it's happening... on my sandbox link I can´t edit too, It's working for you there?

Comment: This won't work, you are removing everything else in `userEdit`.'